# Access database from ACL plugin

Tags: database, zend-framework, plugins, acl

I want to load resources from database inside the ACL plugin

I make like this

```
 class My_ACL extends Zend_Acl {

protected $_role_id;
protected $_userResource;

public function __construct() {

    try {
        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $stmt = $db->query("CALL getUserPrivileges(?)", 998877445);

        //Returns an array containing all of the result set rows  
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $stmt->closeCursor();
        print_r($rows);

        return $rows;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'error ' . $e;
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work since white page is rendered and nothing is print out!

Comment: white pages means that : an error has occurred and its hidden becuase of some php.ini setting , check apache error or enable showing error

Comment: I am making online testing, I cannot check the appache server, but I make like this in application.ini filephpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

Comment: these setting must be applied on the production stage , not in development , could you please double check it again

Comment: On [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info), about half way down there is a FAQ on how to reveal the errors your script is trying to report to you. read it and post your error messages here if they don't make sense to you. Make sure you read them, try to understand them and act on them first though.

Comment: are you sure you want extend Zend_Acl in this case most plugins extend Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract and put the Acl logic in preDispatch().

Comment: I define an class of ACL and make an object from it inside the plugin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was calling default data adapter before initializing the default adapter, the trick was I have to get the data adapter inside the bootstrap and pass it to the plugin, so I make like this

in bootstrap file

```
protected function _initPlugins() {
    $this->bootstrap('db');
    $db = $this->getResource('db');
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_Acl($db));
}
```

and in the Application_Plugin_Acl, I make like this

```
class Application_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

 public function __construct($db) {
    $this->_acl = new My_ACL($db);
}
}
```

and here's my_ACL

```
 class My_ACL extends Zend_Acl {


public function __construct($db) {

     try {

      $stmt = $db->query("CALL getUserPrivileges(?)", 998877445);

      //Returns an array containing all of the result set rows
      $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

      $stmt->closeCursor();
      print_r($rows);

      return $rows;
      } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo 'error ' . $e;
      }

}
```